# Using Conditions to Trigger an alert through Power Automate when threshold is reached

Tags: power-automate

I'm currently working on a project for Power Automate to read this hourly email that is sent to my Inbox, detailing key indicators for the database servers that I am maintaining.

I was tasked to make a flow where Power Automate triggers an alert when key indicators breach the minimum threshold so that the team can rectify issues with the servers.

However, I don't really know how to go about building the flow, especially with the condition part of the flow.

Here's a small snippet of the email:

```html
<td style="width: 300px; text-align: center;"><strong>System Start Date Time:</strong></td>
<td style="width: 300px; text-align: center;">04 July 2022 02:53 PM</td>
```

In this example, I need the condition flow to focus on the date-time provided. As there are multiple of such date-times throughout the email, using the contains() condition is ruled out. Would appreciate any input at all and will be willing to provide a more detailed explanation if need be. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [indexOf](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#indexOf) function to check in a trigger condition if a certain substring can be found in the body/body property. With an equals and not you can output a boolean. This way the flow will only trigger if it has found the text 'System Start Date Time'.

```
@not(equals(indexOf(triggerOutputs()?['body/body'], 'System Start Date Time:'), -1))
```

After that you can retrieve the date time value. Since the HTML will always be the same (I assume) you can use three [split](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#split) functions. Split on the 'System Start Date Time' text, return the second part (by using index 1). From the second part you can split on the begin and end td tags.

```
split(split(split(triggerOutputs()?['body/body'], 'System Start Date Time:')[1], '<td style="width:300px; text-align:center">')[1], '</td>')[0]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Expiscornovus thanks for the reply. I tried your method and it works. 

However, it seems like the code will only work for months that are 4 letters long like 'July' and 'June' since it is specific to only pickup 21 characters. Is there a workaround around this issue? 

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You are totally right. Forgot about the MMM format. Months can obviously have shorter or longer names, my bad. Let me edit my proposed answer.

Comment: @MTSW I have updated the answer with a new expression which uses three split functions. Can you test that new approach?

Comment: Tested the new approach and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help! @Expiscornovus